# Can Jasper compiler XML external entities in web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xml-parsing, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7.0.52 and a project which pre-compiles JSPs using Jasper. To do this, I'm using Ant to run [`org.apache.jasper.JspC`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html) on my input JSPs.

Part of Jasper's thing is it needs to process my `web.xml`. The problem is that my `web.xml` is set up to include a bunch of shared boilerplate using XML entities. So it looks a litte bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE WebAppCommon [
    <!ENTITY CommonContextParams SYSTEM "common-context-params.entity">
]>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="3.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    ...
    &CommonContextParams;
    ...
</web-app>
```

This makes Jasper explode. The error message I get is:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [null] with public ID [null], system ID [common-context-params.entity] and base URI [/path/to/project/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml] to a known, local entity.

I've looked in detail at the `JspC` class to no avail. I've also scoured the internet without any luck. Most people having this problem seem to be having it because of a restriction called `allowExternalEntities=false` in Tomcat's Context. But I'm still at the build stage, so this isn't my problem!

**Can anyone tell me of a configuration item I can change to make Jasper accept my external entity?**

Here's a heavily edited stack trace:

```
/path/to/project/build.xml:88: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: XML parsing error on file file:/path/to/project/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig.processWebDotXml(JspConfig.java:230)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig.init(JspConfig.java:243)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig.isJspPage(JspConfig.java:465)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.scanFiles(JspC.java:1285)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1340)
    ...  ...    
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    ...  ...    
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: XML parsing error on file file:/path/to/project/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.ParserUtils.parseXMLDocument(ParserUtils.java:152)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig.processWebDotXml(JspConfig.java:95)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [null] with public ID [null], system ID [common-context-params.entity] and base URI [file:/path/to/project/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml] to a known, local entity.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.LocalResolver.resolveEntity(LocalResolver.java:154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolver2Wrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolver2Wrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1209)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1908)
    ...  ...
```

Comment: where do you keep the `common-context-params.entity`?

Comment: @wero, same directory as web.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run JspC with the (undocumented) command-line parameter

```
-no-blockExternal
```

which should have the same effect as `allowExternalEntities=true` in the context.

---

The [Jasper Ant task](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation) can set this flag using the parameter `blockexternal`:

```
<jasper blockexternal="false" ... />
```

Comment: what if I'm running it as an Ant task? Is it possible to simulate that parameter?

Comment: do you use the jasper task as described here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation ?

Comment: more or less. We technically have wrapped the JspC class in our own Ant taskdef...

Comment: it worked!!!!! Thank you so much. I seriously can't thank you enough for this -- it was so frustrating and you've just cleared away all the problems!